# LCJS AreaSeries FillStyle misbehaves on chart containing 2 series

Tags: javascript, charts, lightningchart

## Requirement

Want to setup a chart which updates progressively. When user gives a trigger, series should change the color of currently updating part for a short time (Color of the whole chart should not change).

## Approach

To achieve this, I'm using [`lcjs.iife v3.4.0`](https://github.com/Arction/lcjs-html-example/blob/9c1a93784730537a313af1b2a084b7abb4e2a223/lcjs.iife.js) `ChartXY` with 2 `AreaSeries` (Bipolar). At the time of trigger, AreaSeries-1 stops updating and AreaSeries2 starts updating from where the earlier stopped. A NaN is appended to each AreaSeries after stopping, to break continuity.

## Issue

But unexpectedly, the AreaFill is missing in some cycles of the sine chart. In the attached image, the yellow stroke is the trigger and the next 2 positive cycle's fill is missing

What is the fix to this issue? or any alternate approach?

[image: LightningChart ChartXY AreaSeries]

## Codes

### index.html

```html
<div id="chart1" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>
<button>Trigger</button>
<script src="lcjs.iife.js"></script>    <!-- lcjs.iife v3.4.0 -->
<script src="lightning_chart.js"></script>
<script>
    const btn = document.querySelector('button')
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.querySelector('button').disabled = true
        invertColor(1)
        setTimeout(() => {
            invertColor(0)
            document.querySelector('button').disabled = false
        }, 1000)
    })
</script>
```

### lightning_chart.js

```js
// Extract required parts from LightningChartJS.
const {
    lightningChart,
    SolidLine, SolidFill,
    ColorRGBA, ColorHEX, emptyFill, ColorCSS, UIElementBuilders, emptyLine,
    Themes, customTheme, UIBackgrounds, UIDirections,
    ColorPalettes, UILayoutBuilders, UIOrigins, UIVisibilityModes, MarkerBuilders,
    FontSettings, IndividualPointFill, translatePoint,
    AxisScrollStrategies, AxisTickStrategies, synchronizeAxisIntervals,
    AreaSeriesTypes, PointShape,
    AutoCursorModes,
} = lcjs //Note: @arction/lcjs is not needed here, when using IIFE assembly


const color = "#36a2eb"
const inverseColor = "#c89600"
let colorInvertFlag = 0
let x = 0
const titleFont = new FontSettings({
    family: "Roboto, sans-serif",
    size: 28,
    weight: 500
});
const positiveColorFill = new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX(color) });
const negativeColorFill = new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX(color).getLighter().getLighter() });
const positiveColorFillInverse = new SolidFill({color: ColorHEX(inverseColor)});
const negativeColorFillInverse = new SolidFill({color: ColorHEX(inverseColor).getLighter().getLighter()});
const fillAlpha = 50;


/** Create chart */
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({
    theme: Themes.newDark, 
    container: 'chart1',
    disableAnimations: true
})
.setTitle('') // Set chart title
.setBackgroundFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorRGBA(5, 28, 53, 255) }))
.setBackgroundStrokeStyle(new SolidLine({thickness: 2, fillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorRGBA(10, 56, 106) })}))
.setMouseInteractions(false)
.setAutoCursorMode(AutoCursorModes.disabled)

const data = []
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i += 1) {
    // data.push({ x: i, y: Math.random() * 1000 });
}


/** Create Y axis */
chart.getDefaultAxisY()
.setTitle(`${this.name} (${this.unit})`)
.setTitleFont(titleFont)
.setTitleFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX("#93b0bf") }))
.setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.Numeric)
.setInterval(0, 1000)
.setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.fitting)
.setStrokeStyle(new SolidLine({ thickness: 2, fillStyle: positiveColorFill }))
.setMouseInteractions(false)


/** Create X axis*/
chart.getDefaultAxisX()
.setTitle('')
.setInterval(0, 6000)
.setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.progressive)
.setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.Empty)
.setStrokeStyle(new SolidLine({ thickness: 2, fillStyle: positiveColorFill }))
.setMouseInteractions(false)


/** Create primary line */
const line = chart.addAreaSeries({
    dataPattern: {
        pattern: 'ProgressiveX',
        regularProgressiveStep: true,
    },
    type: AreaSeriesTypes.Bipolar,
    automaticColorIndex: 2
})
.setName('Primary-line')
.add(data)
.setMaxPointCount(10000)
.setMouseInteractions(false)
.setPositiveStrokeStyle(new SolidLine({thickness: 2, fillStyle: positiveColorFill}))
.setPositiveFillStyle(positiveColorFill.setA(fillAlpha))
.setNegativeStrokeStyle(new SolidLine({thickness: 2, fillStyle: negativeColorFill}))
.setNegativeFillStyle(negativeColorFill.setA(fillAlpha))

        
/** Create secondary line */
const lineInv = chart.addAreaSeries({
    dataPattern: {
        pattern: 'ProgressiveX',
        regularProgressiveStep: true,
    },
    type: AreaSeriesTypes.Bipolar,
    automaticColorIndex: 2
})
.setName('Secondary-line')
.setMaxPointCount(10000)
.setMouseInteractions(false)
.setPositiveStrokeStyle(new SolidLine({thickness: 2, fillStyle: positiveColorFillInverse}))
.setPositiveFillStyle(positiveColorFillInverse.setA(fillAlpha))
.setNegativeStrokeStyle(new SolidLine({thickness: 2, fillStyle: negativeColorFillInverse}))
.setNegativeFillStyle(negativeColorFillInverse.setA(fillAlpha))


function invertColor(invert) {
    if (invert != this.colorInvertFlag) {
        colorInvertFlag = invert
        // break series continuity
        if (invert) line.add({x: x, y: NaN})
        else lineInv.add({x: x, y: NaN})
    }
}

function update(newX, newY) {
    try {
        if (colorInvertFlag) lineInv.add({ x: x, y: newY });
        else line.add({ x: x, y: newY });
    } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e, x, newY);
    }
    x++;
}

let _i = 0;
const chartDummyDataInterval = setInterval(() => {
    update(_i, Math.sin(_i / 100) * 100)
    _i++;
}, 10)
```

Comment: It seems to be a bug in that version of lcjs. I get a repeated`GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Vertex buffer is not big enough for the draw call` error whenever the strange behavior happens. Possible empirical solution (I have no explanation): it appears it doesn't like `y: NaN` in that context, however if  `{x: NaN, y:0}` is used to break the series, I don't get any errors.

Comment: Not sure I understood the requirement correctly, but using NaN points doesn't seem like a perfect fit there. One thing you can try is using PalettedFill fill style with lookUpProperty 'x' to color a specific time range differently.